# Debugging an ASP.NET MVC site and ASP.NET MVC Source Code

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been given an app written by someone else and the error I get when I try to just launch the thing and the first look at it is:

"There is no source code available for the current location."

I could care less about the source code to ASP.NET MVC. How do I tell my project to show me the location where it is breaking in "my" code?

**Update:**
The message I get after this initial error is "no controller named ~"

After all this the app still works. Its just really slow. Any ideas?
Each page request goes through this cycle in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a routing issue.  Can you please post the RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax?

If it is using the default, then a request is being made to http://sitelocation/~/somethingelsehere.

My guess is there is a reference to a url like "~/Public/default.aspx".

Comment: That was it a url ref like "~/something"

Answer (score 0):

Some basic things to check:

1. The MVC is the startup project
2. The Default.aspx is the startup page

Edit:

What does the Global.asx.cs page look like? Can you post some code? I am wondering if it's somewhere in the routing...